# Problem with minimization of $x^z$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have plugged in the following problem

```
Minimize[{x^z, z >= 1, z <= 10, x >= 1}, {x, z}]
```

Can anyone explain please why the software does not provide the analytical solution? Clearly NMinimize is possible to use, but I am interested in the analytical solution which is $x=1$ and $1 \leq z\leq10$.

Comment: But z is bounded by 1 and i am interested in the theoretical solution

Comment: The software has a problem with the power argument and I am wondering why

Comment: Minimize[{z*Log[x], z >= 1 && z <= 10 && x >= 1}, {z, x}] does not work too. I think the extrema located at the boundary make a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the **Karush-Kuhn-Tucker** equations with **Reduce**, to do symbolic optimization code from [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1402471?p_p_auth=qKI8Hqb2) we get:

```
KTEqs[obj_ (*objective function*), cons_List (*constraints*), 
vars_List (*variables*)] := 
Module[{consconvrule = {GreaterEqual[x_, y_] -> LessEqual[y - x, 0], 
Equal[x_, y_] -> Equal[x - y, 0], 
LessEqual[x_, y_] -> LessEqual[x - y, 0], 
LessEqual[lb_, x_, ub_] -> LessEqual[(x - lb) (x - ub), 0], 
GreaterEqual[ub_, x_, lb_] -> LessEqual[(x - lb) (x - ub), 0]}, 
x, y, lb, ub, stdcons, eqcons, ineqcons, lambdas, mus, lagrangian, 
eqs1, eqs2, eqs3, alleqns, 
allvars},(*Change constraints to Equal and LessEqual form with \
zero on the right-hand side*)stdcons = cons /. consconvrule;
(*Separate the equality constraints and the inequality constraints*)
eqcons = Cases[stdcons, Equal[_, 0]][[All, 1]];
ineqcons = Cases[stdcons, LessEqual[_, 0]][[All, 1]];
(*Define the Lagrange multipliers for the equality and inequality \
constraints*)lambdas = Array[\[Lambda], Length[eqcons]];
mus = Array[\[Mu], Length[ineqcons]];
(*Define the Lagrangian*)
lagrangian = obj + lambdas.eqcons + mus.ineqcons;
(*The derivatives of the Lagrangian are equal to zero*)
eqs1 = Thread[D[lagrangian, {vars}] == 0];
(*Lagrange multipliers for inequality constraints \
are\[GreaterEqual]0 to get minima*)eqs2 = Thread[mus >= 0];
(*Lagrange multipliers for inequality constraints are 0 unless the \
constraint value is 0*)eqs3 = Thread[mus*ineqcons == 0];
(*Collect the equations*)alleqns = Join[eqs1, eqs2, eqs3, cons];
(*Collect the variables*)allvars = Join[vars, lambdas, mus];
(*Return the equations and the variables*){alleqns, allvars}]; 
torules[res_] := 
If[Head[res] === And, ToRules[res], List @@ (ToRules /@ res)]; 
KKTReduce[obj_(*objective function*), cons_List (*constraints*), 
vars_List (*variables*)] := 
Block[{kkteqs, kktvars, red, rls, objs, allres, minobj, sel, ret, 
minred, minredrls},(*Construct the equations and the \
variables*){kkteqs, kktvars} = KTEqs[obj, cons, vars];
(*Reduce the equations*)
red = LogicalExpand@
Reduce[kkteqs, kktvars, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True];
(*Convert the Reduce results to rules (if possible)*)
rls = torules[red];
(*If the conversion to rules was complete*)
If[Length[Position[rls, _ToRules]] == 
0,(*Calculate the values of the objective function*)
objs = obj /. rls;
(*Combine the objective function values with the rules*)
allres = Thread[{objs, rls}];
(*Find the minimum objective value*)minobj = Min[objs];
(*Select the results with the minimum objective value*)
sel = Select[allres, #[[1]] == minobj &];
(*Return the minimum objective value with the corresponding rules*)
ret = {minobj, 
sel[[All, 2]]},(*Else if the results were not completely converted to \
rules*)(*Use MinValue to find the smallest objective function value*)
minobj = MinValue[{obj, red}, kktvars];
(*Use Reduce to find the corresponding results*)
minred = 
Reduce[obj == minobj && red, kktvars, Reals, 
Backsubstitution -> True];
(*Convert results to rules,if possible*)minredrls = torules[minred];
ret = If[
Length[Position[minredrls, _ToRules]] == 0, {minobj, 
minredrls}, {minobj, minred}];];
(*Remove excess nesting from result*)
If[Length[ret[[2]]] == 1 && Depth[ret[[2]]] > 1, {ret[[1]], 
ret[[2, 1]]}, ret]];

KKTReduce[x^z, {z >= 1, z <= 10, x >= 1}, {x, z}]

(* {1, (x == 1 && z == 1 && μ[1] == 0 && μ[2] == 0 && μ[3] == 
1) || (x == 1 && z == 10 && μ[1] == 0 && μ[2] == 0 && μ[3] == 
10) || (x == 1 && 1 <= z <= 10 && μ[1] == 0 && μ[2] == 0 && μ[3] == z)} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mariusz Iwaniuk, I tried to apply the code but it doesn't seem to work. Can you please show how you do it?

Comment: @Y.L.I edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually with situations like this, it's because your solution may end up having a complex solution, if you don't add boundries, to say Reals, or Integers..However, after modifying your code some to:

```
Minimize[{x^z, Element[x | z, Reals], z >= 1, z <= 10, x >= 1}, {x, z}]
```

I also could not get it to evaluate a solution.

I suspect this just is too much for Minimize to handle.

Thankfully, `NMinimize` is here to save the day.

```
NMinimize[{x^z, z >= 1, z <= 10, x >= 1}, {x, z}]
```

or

```
NMinimize[{x^z,Element[x | z, Reals], z >= 1, z <= 10, x >= 1}, {x, z}]

{*{1., {x -> 1., z -> 10.}}*}
```

Which gives you a solution, minimized with respect to x, in your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In theory `Minimize[]` should return a single point from your optimum line `x==1`. Not sure the internal algorithm it uses, or why it stumbles on this, but it is not designed to return a range anyway.

When you put in a constraint on `x==1` then the function seems to always return a value halfway between lower and upper bounds on `z`, for example...

```
Minimize[{x^z, 1 <= z <= 100, x == 1}, {x, z}]

(* {1, {x -> 1, z -> 50}} *)
```